# Question about groovy scripts recognition by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I guess by asking this I might sound a bit illegible, but I'm still unsure as to how to approach the problem.

In my spring project (not really my, work stuff) I've got some groovy scripts which are initially treated as resources, yet in reality they are rather the "source code" which is compiled not during the gradle assembly of the project but during the runtime by the application itself. And everything's fine with that.

The problem is that the IDE doesn't treat the groovy file properly. Dumb example to somehow describe what I mean:

```
import myproject.example.blabla
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class SomeClass1 implements SomeClass2 {
    private final SomeClass2 someName1

    SomeClass1() {
        someName1 = new something
    }

    @Override
    String getSmth() {
        return someName1.getSmth()
    }
}
```

The problems:

- when I make "<kbd>command</kbd> + left_click" on `SomeClass2`, it says `Cannot find declaration to go to`, but when I press "<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>" it finds the file because it actually exists
- `.getSmth()` is red, because `Cannot resolve symbol`

So it seems that I need to somehow show the dependencies via gradle to IDE *only*. Like, somehow specify the dependencies explicitly for IntelliJ IDEA so that it would understand that it is a source code as well and stop underlining everything with red.

Comment: does your build.gradle has groovy plugin? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Such files must be located in the module's [**Source Root**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories) directory for the IDE to recognize them as sources and so that navigation would also work.

In a Gradle-based project IDE [configures](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_source_sets) **Source Roots** automatically based on the Gradle's [**Source Sets**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) configuration. For each Gradle source set IDE creates a module with one **Source Root** directory.

So you must configure Gradle to create source set for the directories where these files are located: add them into [default sources](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-source-sets#default-src-sets) sets or create a [custom source set](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-source-sets#custom-src-sets) for them.